# SQL: Distinct based on 1 field

Tags: sql, sqlite, distinct

I have a data set with duplicate city names. I wish to get all the records and if the city is duplicated, then just get the first one:

```
1  London  Fred
2  Paris   Sally
3  London  Marce
```

I want this returned:

```
1  London  Fred
2  Paris   Sally
```

I'm using SQLite, but that shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: What defines first? SQL has no implicit ordering.

Comment: select min(id) from the table, group by city. Wrap in subquery, perform inner join with the table by id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableName a
(
    SELECT countryName, MIN(id) minID
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY countryName
) b ON a.id = b.minID 
         -- AND a.countryName = b.countryName
```

Comment: `a.countryName = b.countryName` probably is not necessary here